# Unit test coverage for async private function

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I using SpringBoot and I have to write unit test for a function that call another private function by TaskExecutor. The problem is the unit test cannot cover the private function. Here is the code:
ThreadConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadConfig {

  @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }
}
```

Service.java:

```
@Service
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("taskExecutor") 
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

      public String test() {
          Runnable task = this::task;
          taskExecutor.execute(task);
          return "OK";
       }
      private void task(){
          System.out.println("Test");
      }
}
```

ServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

  @Mock(name = "taskExecutor")
  private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

  @InjectMocks private Service service;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    final String expected = "OK";
    Mockito.doNothing().when(taskExecutor).execute(Matchers.any(Runnable.class));
    assertEquals(expected, service.test());
  }
}
```

The test can coverage test() function but cannot coverage task() function

Comment: "*The test can coverage `test()` function but cannot coverage `task()` function*" - Why should it cover `task()`? A unit-test should test one thing and one thing only. Furthermore, you (normally) test the interfaces (i.e. public methods). You can set the method `protected` (or `[default]`) and write the unit test in the same package as your class. This would allow you to test the `task()` method independently.

Comment: But as I know, it will automatically cover all private method when we test the public method that call the private method

Comment: The problem is that you are not calling this private method, because you tell mockito to do nothing, instead of running your private method. You can check it putting a breakpoint inside.

Comment: @staszko032 can you help me how to call it in the test ?

Comment: Try to change `Mockito.doNothing().when(taskExecutor).execute(Matchers.any(Runnable.class));` to `Mockito.when(taskExecutor.execute(any())).thenCallRealMethod();`

If it is not working, try to use a Spy object from Mockito.